# Mutlistep Cleaning/Regex: Substitution & Extract Portion Before Separator

Tags: r, regex, paste, gsub

I have a matrix `M` with row names as below;

```
S003_T1_p555
S003_T2_p456
S004_T3_p785
S004_T4_p426
SuperSMART_27_T1_p112
SuperSMART_27_T2_p414
SuperSMART_42_T3_p155
SuperSMART_42_T5_p775
```

I would like to make a function to:

1. substitute `SuperSMART_` with `S` in rows that this is the case
2. then extract only characters before the first `_` as keys and
   assign a unique name to each similar individual

So both `S003_T1_p555` and `S003_T2_p456` become `"group1"`, `S004_T3_p785` and `S004_T4_p426` `"group2"`, and so on.

### MWE

```
nms <- c("S003_T1_p555", "S003_T2_p456", "S004_T3_p785", "S004_T4_p426", 
    "SuperSMART_27_T1_p112", "SuperSMART_27_T2_p414", 
    "SuperSMART_42_T3_p155", "SuperSMART_42_T5_p775")

M <- matrix(
    seq_along(nms),
    dimnames = list(
        nms,
        'x'    
    )
)
```

Comment: I wish that this question hadn't been closed so hastily.  Broad does not seem to fit this.  Looks more like you are a newer poster that needs patience and a few edits. Here is a solution as a gist since I can't post here after it was closed: https://gist.github.com/trinker/f90b28662a728b708124bb4f26a375dc

Please keep asking questions here and work to make your questions a bit more clear.  This is a good place to start for improving questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TylerRinker wish everybody here was thinking like you! thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If I get it right, shouldn't the number after the first _ be 0 padded to be on 3 digits as the first rows ?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(M, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    rownames_to_column('id') %>%
    mutate(
        id = gsub('SuperSMART_', 'S', id), 
        id = gsub('(^S)(\\d{2})(_)', '\\10\\2\\3', id, perl = TRUE) 
    ) %>%
    separate(id, into = c('S', 'R', 'p'), sep = '_', remove = FALSE) %>%  
    mutate(., group = group_indices(., S))

##             id    S  R    p x group
## 1 S003_T1_p555 S003 T1 p555 1     1
## 2 S003_T2_p456 S003 T2 p456 2     1
## 3 S004_T3_p785 S004 T3 p785 3     2
## 4 S004_T4_p426 S004 T4 p426 4     2
## 5 S027_T1_p112 S027 T1 p112 5     3
## 6 S027_T2_p414 S027 T2 p414 6     3
## 7 S042_T3_p155 S042 T3 p155 7     4
## 8 S042_T5_p775 S042 T5 p775 8     4


## If you really want it as a function:
normalize_data <- function(m, ..) {
    as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column('id') %>%
        dplyr::mutate(
            id = gsub('SuperSMART_', 'S', id), 
            id = gsub('(^S)(\\d{2})(_)', '\\10\\2\\3', id, perl = TRUE) 
        ) %>%
        tidyr::separate(id, into = c('S', 'R', 'p'), sep = '_', remove = FALSE) %>%  
        dplyr::mutate(., group = dplyr::group_indices(., S))
}
```

So this is a groupped capture denoted by the parenthesis `'(^S)(\d{2})(_)'`.  There are 3 groups being captured.  1: `(^S)`, 2:`(\d{2})`, 3: `(_)`.  The first one says grab from the beginning (`^`) and `S`.  The second group says grab after that where there are exactly 2 digits (`\\d{2}`) and then the 3rd group says it must be followed by an underscore.

So `S27_T2_p414`  would be matched by this but `S004_T3_p785` would not.

For the replacment of `'\10\2\3'`....If it matches  `'(^S)(\d{2})(_)'` we can use `perl = TRUE` to replace the group capturing (denoted by parenthesis above.  The `\1` corresponds to `(^S)` ; the `\2` corresponds to `(\d{2})` AND `\3` goes with `(_)`.  We can insert things in between the capture groups.  This technique is called [backreference](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). In this case I insert an extra zero between the first capture group and the second to ensure all numbers have 3 digits.  This makes an assumption that at most you have 3 digits in the string after `S`.